# Can we Taylor expand an integrand at pole for a convergent integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals

I have a definite integral $$S(q)=\int dx f(q,x),$$ which is an odd function in the parameter $q$. Also, $q=0$ is a pole of the integrand $f$ due to terms like the form below $$F(q)=\frac{B(q)}{(A(q=0)-A(q))^3},$$ where argument $x$ is suppressed for brevity, $A,B$ are some smooth functions and $B(q=0)=0$. The integral converges well for any finite $q$ in numerical integration and approaches $S(q=0)=0$ as expected from the oddness and the definition of the underlying physical problem.

Now I want to study the leading, i.e., $q$-linear, order of contribution of this. But the Taylor expansion coefficient of the integrand $$c_1=f'(q)|_{q=0}$$ diverges due to the pole.
I then found that maybe I can (repeatedly) apply [L'Hôpital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule) to $c_1$ by considering the limit $$c_1=\lim_{q\rightarrow0}f'(q),$$
which does become finite eventually. And each time I use this rule, the condition of vanishing numerator and denominator is indeed satisfied. Then presumably, the $q$-linear order of the integral $S(q)$ is given by $$q\int dx\, c_1(x).$$
I numerically found that this does seem to reproduce $S(q)$ at very small $q$.

Does this make sense at all and why? Or if any other way to obtain the leading-order behavior in $q$?

Comment: Are you repeatedly applying L'Hopital's rule to the terms of the form $F(q)$, or something else? In general, you can't expect to get meaningful linear order estimates of a function near a pole; the best analog is Laurent series to get, say, the $O(q^{-1})$ coefficient. For example, for poles like $1/q$, all terms in the Laurent series are zero, except for the $1/q$ term.

Comment: @kieransquared Yes, I repeatedly apply L'Hopital's rule (for q) to the integrand with terms like $F(q,x)$. But the present integral doesn't have $O(1/q)$ and is odd in $q$.

Comment: You can only apply L'hopital's to limits of the form $\frac{0}{0}$ or $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, so you'll need derivatives of $B$ up to order 2 to vanish at 0. Also, the $O(1/q)$ is just an example; my point is that the best you can do in general is get an estimate on the growth of the singularity. Being odd in $q$ doesn't seem like it helps, because you're only integrating in $x$, correct? Any odd power of $x$ is odd, but may still have a singularity at zero for negative powers. If your numerical results are suggesting that $S(0) = 0$, then there's likely some cancellation going on.

Comment: @kieransquared What if derivatives of $B(q)$ indeed vanish up to the order required by applying L'hopital's rule enough times?

Comment: Of course, it depends on $A$ as well, since you introduce terms of the form $A'(q)$ each time you differentiate the denominator. It might just be easier to give the explicit form of your integrand.